# Apache2.4 configuration files with backward compatability for apache2.2

Tags: apache, apache2.2, apache2.4

I have some apache configuration files that needs to be run on apache2.4 server as well as apache2.2. Some directives are changed, the most prominent are:

(2.2)

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

(2.4)

```
Require all denied
```

However, I want to run the same conf file on both 2.2 and 2.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use < [IfVersion](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_version.html#ifversion) > which can separate conf files sections according to the apache server version running:

```
<IfVersion >= 2.4>
     Require all granted
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion <= 2.2>
    Order allow,deny 
    Allow from all 
</IfVersion>
```